# error mounting a zip drive when I specify a uid

Tags: mount, uid

I have a zip drive which my system recognizes as `/dev/sda`

when I try to mount it with this command

```
sudo /bin/mount -t ext4 /dev/sda /mnt/usb -o rw,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

it throws this error

```
mount: /mnt/usb: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

when I mount it with this command:

```
sudo /bin/mount -t ext4 /dev/sda /mnt/usb -o rw,nosuid
```

it opens find, but of course, files are owned by root, which is annoying.

Could somebody please tell me how to mount it so that I own everything?

thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to not use `chown` at the mount point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mount an `ext4` file system that fully supports linux file permissions. The `uid` option applies to mounting file systems that do not support linux permissions.

Mount it as root, then change the permissions and/or ownership of the mount point as you see fit.